# Who is actually learning? Is it Atman or me?

Tags: brahman, atma

If I am learning something like learning physics or chemistry or maths means who is learning? Is it Atman or my brain?

If Atman means why can't it (Atman) realize after death that I belong to this body and then I will enter back to this same body.

If it is just my brain, my brain is learning about Brahman now, then how my Atman will remember that oh okay I am actually Brahman, so I should merge with brahman and this body is not real.

I am looking for connectivity between brain and Atman. How brain will send the information to my Atman that I am Brahman.

Comment: You are almost there to realize the atman you should loose your identity to realize the brahman i.e. atman (loose your brain in your terms) Loose your brain to get to brahman (Advaita in a nutshell)But unfortunately im a tattva vadist (Dualist) so I will retain my brain.. and also I will realize brahman :-)

Comment: Ahamkara is what you think as you. Its from this all thoughts arise and you think you are different from ATMA. Learner is mind. But the stage where you realize the learner is mind is Atma.

Comment: what do you mean by Atman **OR** me ? Atman = me

Comment: Akshay would have ment me=Ahankara but atman=brahman @ram if you destroy the me or Ahamkara there you are

Comment: People who are learning advaita should not use the word atman to refer to the individual self. As per Shankara, Atman is the universal self and jiva is the individual self. There's only one or ekam. And that's Atman aka Brahman, present everywhere. All living and non living things dwells in the infinite body/feild of Atman.

Comment: The mind or ego is also known by names such as jiva, sookshma sharira and linga sharira. It is the false self or individual, empirical, illusory self. We should drop this false self and think of ourselves as the real supreme self thats is Atman the omnipresent spirit/consciousness.

Comment: I think Atman the universal spirit knows everything. But when Atman superimposes it's shakti maya on ITSELF. (i.e. when atman makes itself forgetful by associating itself with mind or ego which are products of maya) then IT remains as the seeker or learner. A perfect example would be, a rich millionaire after losing his memory thinks himself as a common folk or beggar and keeps enquiring about his true identity.

Comment: So loosing memory will eventually lead to brahman ie. Alzhmier patient are loosing memory and their identity In end case alzhmier the patient should have reached brahman @TheCrimsonUniverse

Comment: @Prasanna, loosing memory doesn't leads to Brahman, but dropping your false ego driven self does. Even after you drop ur ego, u don't loose ur memory and yet attain Brahman. Get my point? Go thru my comment above again.

Comment: who is super imposing on who, why it get superimposed.. Advaitic  brahma gnani (those realized) According to Advaita Suthala, Sushma, linga should be destroyed to get to brahman. because everything is false, once this gnani attains brahma hood his body should not exists if it exists then by same advaita argument the brahma hood attained by gnani is false. once false is destroyed, the brahman should not have all the fallicies why this contradiction

Comment: @PrasannaR, Once brahmahood is attained while living in the body it's called jivan mukta state. In such a situation, the subtle and gross bodies exists but the self realized one doesn't recognize itself with the subtle and gross bodies. Such a jnani person, doesn't possess any greed, lust or jealousy. In other words such a person even while dwelling in the bodies of maya, dwells above maya ... And regarding ur question, why it gets superimposed. The answer to that question is, to continue the process of creation. Brahman puts itself in amnesia by using it's shakti maya to keep creation going.

Comment: But there's another type of mukti which u just spoke of in ur comment that the linga sharira should stop existing.  Yes it's true that the linga sharira or subtle body stops existing upon attaining videha mukti (liberation upon death). A self realized jnani uses his mind aka subtle body aka antahkarana to attain Brahman ... and then when he attains brahman and upon death of such a person the subtle body or mind ceases to exist. In short, that person no longer exists. Then only Brahman aka Atman remains. This is called videha mukti.

Comment: another doubt in advaita is what happened to newly liberated brahman.. because the brahman is unchanging (According BS) if its changing then brahman itself is false.. The brahman is already existing outside, this new brahman goes and joins can increase the volume of the already existing brahman in case of eka brahma theory, if its not changing then this brahman should remain separate..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89929/discussion-between-prasanna-r-and-the-crimson-universe).

Comment: Jivan muktha brahman is one and other actual brahman is another existing outside.. then also your eka brahman vada become totally invalid in jivan muktha case as there are 2 brahman one outside and one which is still in maya or illusion of body but know that he is brahman @TheCrimsonUniverse

Comment: adding one drop to ocean you didn't see the change but there is change in volume.. here we are talking about 2 entities 2 are equal one jivan muktha brahman and brahman outside so the volume is doubled..

Comment: @PrasannaR, Brahman is always ONE or ekam. Only a portion of IT (the portion that dwells in the 5 koshas) remains in forgetfulness just so that the cycle of life or samsara can go on. This inner brahman is not separate from outer brahman. One who thinks they are different is still in ignorance. Also, the jivan mukta brahman stays connected with the outer brahman, and this is why the jivan muktas dwell above maya. They see oneness in everything ... There is no such thing as volume or density or length or measurement when it comes to brahman ...  Brahman is infinite.

Comment: if there is oneness before creation this creation is meaningless.. See @TheCrimsonUniverse this advita vs tattvada is clearly handleded in Nyaya Sudha which our tattvavada philosophers master and also we have Nyayamruta and Chandrika written by sage Vyasthirtha detailing about 21 schools of indian taught how it fails to justify its own doctrine everything is clearly written only thing we should have time to read this and know about the deficiency

Comment: I will explain like this using electricity you have grid with 1Kw now you have 10 w bulb in your home, This 10W bulb realized that im electric current, im the same as 1Kw grid supply once this supply is connected this 10W bulb according law of physics should blow up or atleast its fuse is gone but everything is electric current @TheCrimsonUniverse

Comment: I haven't gone through the other schools of hindu philosophies and so i cannot comment on them. I have only studied advaita. The basics, that is... Now, lets Imagine a blank canvas. Think of it as Brahman. Then draw a few galaxies, stars, planets, jivas in that canvas. These are namas and rupas which appears within the vast infinite body/canvas of Brahman. When these rupas or matter appear in the infinite body of brahman, they are automatically pervaded by Brahman. So long story short, every kind of matter or forms remains in the canvas called Brahman and so they are ONE with Brahman(oneness)

Answer (score 2):

That which is learning is the mind.

Atmaa can not be realised through the brain. And it does not need to learn anything as it is already 'Purna' as mentioned in the Mahavakyas.

Gita says:

> न जायते म्रियते वा कदाचि
>
> न्नायं भूत्वा भविता वा न भूयः।
>
> अजो नित्यः शाश्वतोऽयं पुराणो
>
> न हन्यते हन्यमाने शरीरे।।2.20।।
>
> 2.20 Never is this One born, and never does It die; nor is it that having come to exist, It will again cease to be. This One is birthless, eternal, undecaying, ancient; It is not killed when the body is killed.

But brain is born and it dies.

Also,

> इन्द्रियाणि पराण्याहुरिन्द्रियेभ्यः परं मनः।
>
> मनसस्तु परा बुद्धिर्यो बुद्धेः परतस्तु सः।।3.42।।
>
> 3.42 They say that the organs are superior (to the gross body); the mind is superior to the organs; but the intellect is superior to the mind. However, the one who is superior to the intellect is He.

Our brain controls our mind and intellect. Atmaa is beyond these. In fact Atmaa is the Knower and so can not be perceived through the brain. It is realised at the Nirvikalpa-Samadhi samadhi state where there is no functioning of body, mind, intellect and so of  brain.

Comment: Yes Atman is Poorna and knows everything. But when IT associates with ego (in other words) when it puts on the coverings or sheaths called causal, subtle and gross, then it forgets ITS true nature and this forgetful state is the jivahood. In short, the locus of avidya is in Atman itself. Ramakrishna has explained this beautifully. He said, just like a snake keeps poison in his system, the same way Atman too keeps his illusory shakti maya within ITSELF. Due to this reason, whenever Atman manifests as a body, IT forgets ITS true nature.

Comment: Samadhi is defined as mano-nasha

Comment: Without the instrument called Mind, one cannot know Atman or Brahman. The mind is needed. But once we get to know Atman thru the mind, then mind dissolves into Atman. Then mind stops functioning. And this is the reason why many saints after realising Atman/Brahman, cannot explain their experiences since the mind after reaching that stage stops functioning. You then go beyond the mind , but with the help of the mind of course.

Comment: Mind dissolves in intellect and intellect disolves in Atmaa

Comment: Antahkarana is mind. Mind is the tool by using which one gets to know Brahman. That's the belief of the Pratibimba sub school of advaita. Just like a person cannot see his face without a mirror, the same way one cannot attain Brahman without antahkarana or mind. Once brahmahood is attained and mind's function is done, the mind dissolves in Atma/Brahman.

Answer (score 0):

```
ahaṃ nirvikalpo nirākāra rūpo
```

(vibhutvā ca sarvatra sarvendriyāṇaṃ
    na cāsaṅgataṃ naiva muktir na meyaḥ
    cidānandarūpaḥ śivo'ham śivo'ham)

Athma shatakam or nirvanaashtakam.

The self (athma) is beyond thought.(Nirvikalp).
As per Sri Ramana (author of Maha yoga), Nisargadatta maharaj(who has written I am that) the athman is even beyond awareness of 'I am'.

Adwaitha says:-
Till there is this seer and seen as separate entities there is a question of knowledge and ignorance. One they are given up, there is just self.

The people who are in this state are termed as Jnani by us but they are actually beyond ignorance and wisdom.To realize that you are brahman you need to give up duality.

Connectivity between brain and athman is a question in duality. But athmasakshathkar is beyond duality.

Mind learns and unlearns what it has learnt as rightly said in geetha.